# Using case for indexes in oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

I am having the below index defined on one of the tables in Oracle.

```
CASE  WHEN C IS NOT NULL THEN A||','||B||','||C END
```

Initially, I thought the combination of A,B,C separated by commas should be unique when C is not null, but seems like I'm wrong. I did a bit of a research on this as well but could not find a good explanation.

Could someone kindly help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please edit in your question to provide the full create index statement, along with sample data demonstrating what you want to have happen. Which columns should be unique and when?

Comment: Since you haven't included the complete statement this is a bit of a guess, but you could try removing "UNIQUE" from the "CREATE INDEX" statement. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be unique.
But don't forget - uniqueness is an additional cost.
There will be little benefit from such an index, since there will be duplicates of rows for fields A & B when C is NULL.

I suppose it might be worth changing the index function as :

```
a||','||b||case when c is not null then ','||c end
```

This will control duplicates if only columns A and B are used.
Of course, unless your table has other unique indexes using columns A and B.

For demonstration - a short example, with a unique functional index.

N.B. Please, when describing the problem /task, provide a description of the relevant objects (tables,indexes, procedures...etc.).)

**For a test,try**:

```
--ddl
drop table test_tab;
create table test_tab
( a varchar2(3) not null,
  b varchar2(3) not null,
  c varchar2(3),
  idx  varchar2(12) generated always as (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end) virtual
);  
--
create unique index test_tab_i1 on test_tab(idx);

--dml
insert into test_tab(a,b,c) values('a1','b1','c1');
insert into test_tab(a,b,c) values('a1','b2','c2');
insert into test_tab(a,b,c) values('a1','b1',null);
commit;

select * from test_tab;

ANALYZE TABLE test_tab COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR ALL INDEXES;

--get data of idx 
select INDEX_NAME,NUM_ROWS,DISTINCT_KEYS from user_indexes i where i.table_name=upper('test_tab');

--dubt
insert into test_tab(a,b,c) values('a1','b1',null);
commit;
--
ANALYZE TABLE test_tab COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR ALL INDEXES;

--pass2
select * from test_tab;
--get data of idx 
select INDEX_NAME,NUM_ROWS,DISTINCT_KEYS from user_indexes i where i.table_name=upper('test_tab');

--pass3
--dubt
insert into test_tab(a,b,c) values('a1','b1','c1');
```

```
Result: 
Table created.

Index created.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

Statement processed.

Result Set 31
A   B   C   IDX
a1  b1  c1  a1,b1,c1
a1  b2  c2  a1,b2,c2
a1  b1   -   - 
Download CSV
3 rows selected.

Statement processed.

Result Set 32
INDEX_NAME  NUM_ROWS    DISTINCT_KEYS
TEST_TAB_I1 2   2
Download CSV

1 row(s) inserted.

Statement processed.

Statement processed.

Result Set 33
A   B   C   IDX
a1  b1  c1  a1,b1,c1
a1  b2  c2  a1,b2,c2
a1  b1   -   - 
a1  b1   -   - 
Download CSV
4 rows selected.

Result Set 34
INDEX_NAME  NUM_ROWS    DISTINCT_KEYS
TEST_TAB_I1 2   2
Download CSV

ORA-00001: unique constraint (SQL_XKMHFTSRXNSKMGVEDOYSVXZGL.TEST_TAB_I1) violated ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your question is vague, it is interesting. I will try to provide you a possible explanation.

A||','||B is unique if you can guarantee that for 2 distinct values of (A,B), the function A||','||B is not returning the same value.

You need to guarantee that TO_CHAR(A) ||','|| TO_CHAR(B) is unique.

1. I am considering that A and B are NOT NULL.
2. A||','||B is unique if A and B are VARCHAR but it is not the case if you have DATE or TIMESTAMP datatypes. This is not TRUE because TO_CHAR function has default parameters that depend on nls_parameters from your session.

**Testcase** - executing the same queries but changing the nls_date_format and try to create a unique index

```
drop table test;
create table test (a DATE, b VARCHAR2(10), C VARCHAR2(10));

alter session set nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
drop index test;
truncate table test;
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/60),'1','c1');
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/160),'1','c1');
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/80),'2','c2');
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/180),'2','c2');
commit;
create unique index test on test (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end);
select (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end) valfn from test order by B;

alter session set nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy';
truncate table test;
drop index test;
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/60),'1','c1');
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/160),'1','c1');
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/80),'2','c2');
insert into test(a,b,c) values(sysdate+(1/180),'2','c2');
create unique index test on test (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end);
select (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end) valfn from test order by B;
```

output with nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

```
Index TEST created.

VALFN                    
------------------------ 
15/05/2021 08:40:35,1,c1 
15/05/2021 08:25:35,1,c1 
15/05/2021 08:34:35,2,c2 
15/05/2021 08:24:35,2,c2
```

output with nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy'

```
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found

VALFN           
--------------- 
15/05/2021,1,c1
15/05/2021,1,c1 
15/05/2021,2,c2 
15/05/2021,2,c2
```

Then we can see what happened when the indexes were created. We will query the index definition to explain this behavior.

output with nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'

```
alter session set nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
drop table test;
create table test (a DATE, b VARCHAR2(10), C VARCHAR2(10));
create unique index test on test (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end);
select index_name, column_expression from all_ind_expressions where table_name = 'TEST'


INDEX_NAME COLUMN_EXPRESSION                                                                             
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TEST       CASE  WHEN "C" IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR("A",'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')||','||"B"||','||"C" END
```

output with nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy'

```
alter session set nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy';
drop table test;
create table test (a DATE, b VARCHAR2(10), C VARCHAR2(10));
create unique index test on test (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end);
select index_name, column_expression from all_ind_expressions where table_name = 'TEST'

INDEX_NAME COLUMN_EXPRESSION                                                                  
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TEST       CASE  WHEN "C" IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR("A",'dd/mm/yyyy')||','||"B"||','||"C" END
```

As you can see, the index is not the same because it depends on your nls_date_format when the index was created. I always suggest to validate what was the expression used by Oracle when creating the object.

This is the same when creating virtual columns

```
alter session set nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
drop table test;
create table test (a DATE, b VARCHAR2(10), C VARCHAR2(10)
  ,idx  varchar2(50) generated always as (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end) virtual
);
select DATA_DEFAULT from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'TEST' and column_name = 'IDX';

DATA_DEFAULT                                                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
CASE  WHEN "C" IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR("A",'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')||','||"B"||','||"C" END
```

```
alter session set nls_date_format= 'dd/mm/yyyy';
drop table test;
create table test (a DATE, b VARCHAR2(10), C VARCHAR2(10)
  ,idx  varchar2(50) generated always as (case when c is not null then a||','||b||','||c end) virtual
);
select DATA_DEFAULT from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'TEST' and column_name = 'IDX';

DATA_DEFAULT                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
CASE  WHEN "C" IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR("A",'dd/mm/yyyy')||','||"B"||','||"C" END
```

Now, you can add C to this equation and validate why in your case : CASE  WHEN C IS NOT NULL THEN A||','||B||','||C END is not unique

Most of the time, by default the nls_date_format is not including the time.